# Parsing a remote HTML with images

Tags: html, html-parsing

**Hi All,**

Is it possible to find out whether images are updated in a remote HTML page ?

The only way is to parse the remote HTML page and find out all images, then images are downloaded completely in order to find out whether it is updated according to file size ?

Thanks.

Best regards,
**Henry Fok**

Comment: in a remote page on a *different domain* ? are you looking for a client-side (javascript) solution?